# Automatic marking of the closest point between two plotted lines?

Tags: python, graph

Edited based on the comment below. my problem persists.

At the moment I am plotting a graph of two variables and marking the point at which the lines are closest like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
dat = np.loadtxt(fname="data.txt")


plt.plot(dat[:,0], dat[:,1], dat[:,0],dat[:,2])
plt.axvline(x=35, color='k', linestyle='--',label="closest approach")
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1,1),
           bbox_transform=plt.gcf().transFigure)
```

I would like to automate the marking and labeling of the two or three points of closest approach of the two lines but I'm struggling a bit - any ideas?

Comment: I think [`np.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) is a better way of loading the data. The append method is really slow, especially with large datasets.

Comment: thanks - I'm only loading about 150 numbers but I'll make the change. I was trying to give a MWE with the above

Comment: Actually if the two lines are on the same domain (it seems they are), you can just calculate the distance of the same indexes. Something like ```min([abs(y1[i]-y2[i]) for i in range(len(y1))])```